# adding licencing to an app which has already been available and sold in the Android market

Tags: google-play

I have an app already available in the market for a while and already been sold. Up to now without licencing.

Now I like to add licencing.

Is there anything one has to consider or can I just add the licencing and be sure that no user who actually baught the app will have any problems when updating the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that easily. Just make an licence screen with all the info and put it on market so users can update it. 
When they update it first think when the start the app should be your screen with licence text and accept button after that you preserve info in the base for certain user and allow them to access the app.

P.S. You don't need to preserve data for users who have accepted that is one of the options.

Enjoy programming :)